# How to convert time to currentuser timezone?

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

I have datetime field which is coming from api in the below format . I want to store the value in my custom field

```
Response :
{
time :'2022-06-23T14:00:00+05.30'
timezone:'Asia/Kolkata'
}
```

I have tried the below in my apex but not able achieve.

```
String data = '2022-06-23T14:00:00+05.30'; //coming from api
Datetime dt = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"' + data.substringbefore('+') + '"', DateTime.class);
System.debug('datatime from api====' + dt);
String strIST= dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'IST');
System.debug('IST converion as string====' + strIST);
Datetime dtIST= DateTime.valueof(strIST);
System.debug('IST converion as Datetime====' +dtIST);
```

Output is :
[image]

My expected conversion date is **2022-06-23 14:00:00** but i am getting different value. Can anyone please help me to proceed

Comment: Since you have the time with a timezone SID you should be able to take an approach like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/376997/apex-class-day-light-savings-if-statement-to-adjust-for-daylight-savings-bas/377145#377145), by first removing the "+nn:nn" offset from the date/time string and parsing like you are doing, but then using the code I've provided to do the conversion, using the timezone SID from the response.

Comment: It's worth noting also that `System.debug` always shows `Datetime` values in UTC, not user time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code snippet from my other [Q&A answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/376997/apex-class-day-light-savings-if-statement-to-adjust-for-daylight-savings-bas/377145#377145), you should be able to have:

```
String data = '2022-06-23T14:00:00+05.30'; // Coming from the API
String zone = 'Asia/Kolkata'; // Coming from the API
Datetime dt = (Datetime) JSON.deserialize('"' + data.substringBefore('+') + '"', Datetime.class);

// Identify the target time zone
TimeZone target = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone);

// Figure out the offset at this UTC "moment"
Integer offsetAtUTC = target.getOffset(dt);

// Adjust the date/time value to be in the
// target time zone
Datetime targetDatetime = dt.addSeconds(-offsetAtUTC / 1000);

// Now it is in the target time zone, we have
// a new "moment". If the UTC "moment" was
// before a DST transition but the "moment" in
// the target time zone is after that
// transition the calculation will be adrift
Integer offsetAtLocal = target.getOffset(targetDatetime);

if (offsetAtLocal != offsetAtUTC) {
    // There's a drift because of a DST
    // transition. Correct it
    Datetime adjustedDatetime = targetDatetime.addSeconds((offsetAtUTC - offsetAtLocal) / 1000);

    Integer offsetAtAdjusted = target.getOffset(adjustedDatetime);

    // The correction is conditional; if the corrected time is
    // on the same side of the transition as the correction then
    // we need to correct, but we must also correct if leaping
    // forward regardless
    if (offsetAtAdjusted == offsetAtLocal ||
            adjustedDatetime > targetDatetime) {
        targetDatetime = adjustedDatetime;
    }
}

System.debug('Output local: ' + targetDatetime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss a z', target.getID()));
```

At the end of this processing, the `targetDatetime` represents the input date/time in the target time zone (Asia/Kolkata) though actually is a UTC value (which is how Salesforce stores such values). The debug output is:

```
Output local: 2022-06-23 14:00 PM IST
```

Note: the output a given user sees depends on their time zone unless you do explicit formatting to a given time zone like I did here. I did this to demonstrate that the UTC (or as Salesforce call it GMT) value that would be stored does correspond with the input date/time in the given input time zone. Also note that simple `System.debug` logging of a `Datetime` value actually logs the UTC value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to save the value in Datetime field . So i was trying to convert the String to DateTime.valueof(targetDatetime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss a z', target.getID())) but I am getting runtime error as "System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2022-03-23 17:00 PM IST"

Comment: Just assign the `targetDatetime` to your `Datetime` field at the end of the processing. When this field is viewed by a user who is in IST time zone they will see the expected "local" time. If the field is viewed by a user in a different timezone, they will see it in their time zone instead. This is just how Salesforce works.