# Time Ambiguity in DateTime Input for LWC During DST change

Tags: lightning-web-components

Just a very simple DateTime lightning-input

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="datetime" name="dateTimeInput" label={label} timezone={timezone} required={required} read-only={readonly} disabled={disabled} value={datetime} time-style={length} onchange={handleDateTimeChange}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

While you can specify the timezone this is being entered in the issue is that you can not specify if you mean 1:30 summer time or 1:30 winter time even though the winter time is one hour later pictures below.

[image]

Which gives the following output.

[image]

What I am asking is is there a way to deal with this or has someone made their own fancy DateTime selector that can deal with this.

Comment: Does the second component also specify timezone as Europe/London? What is your org timezone? What is the input datetime value being used for here? Just initial setting?

Comment: I am wondering why you require the user to be able to specify a choice of the ambiguous times in the "fall back" scenario? And what happens if the user specifies a non-existent time in the "spring forward" scenario? (See this other [Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/376997/apex-class-day-light-savings-if-statement-to-adjust-for-daylight-savings-bas/377145#377145) for an illustration of these two DST transitions.)

Comment: @PhilW yes sorry the default in the component is to use Europe/London the first has it set explicitly in this case the main issue is that we have had some customers state deliver part XYZ by 01:30 BST and others by 01:30 GMT as we are a 24/7 company the user can only put in 01:30 BST.

Comment: @PhilW the two issues we have had is either

A. They specify 01:30GMT and we insert in 01:30 BST and we deliver at 01:15 GMT it makes it look like on the system that we have delivered it later than the customer requested it to be and have broken our SLA. 

B. This is a last-minute urgent booking our system knows the travel distance and will refuse the delivery even though there is actually enough time just an hour less than expected.

Comment: Have you considered simply changing the timezone selection?

Comment: @PhilW How would I be able to do so? the component itself is blind to whether it is in an ambiguous time or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136821/discussion-between-karllivesey-and-phil-w).